# Objective-c copy a strong property

Tags: objective-c

Should I assign or copy in the following case?

```
@interface Record: NSManagedObject {   
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* location;   
  ...  
}
```

when assigning this property to something else:

```
 @implementation AnyClass {  
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* location;    
    ...   
    -(void)copyValuesFromRecord:(Record *)last {  
       self.location = [last.location copy];   
       or   
       self.location = last.location
    }
 }
```

How do I reason about this? Does it matter one way or the other?
What if what I need to copy is an object of mine.

Comment: For `NSString` it should be `self.location = last.location` only.